# I am receiving "IndexError: list index out of range" message in python code

Tags: python

I have made my question short with respect to input and expected output.

```
Input
######
a = [[1,2,3],[10,20,30],[4,5,6],[40,50,60],[1,2,3],[11,22,33],[4,5,6],[44,55,66]]

Output
#######
1,10,11
2,20,22
3,30,33
4,40,44
5,50,55
6,60,66
```

Comment: Your question is too broad to read for me. I didn't down voted it though.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and about [minimal examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry about that, I just tried to detail it.

Comment: I can see you're trying to improve the question, and it's appreciated - but I think your editing has gone a little far. Without the code causing issues, it's near-impossible to help.

Answer (score 0):

The `odd_list` and `even_list` have at most half the number of elements from `raw_array`. So you'll get an error when you iterate with `counter in range(len(raw_array))`.

I'm not sure if I got your scenario correctly, but the nested for loops at the end don't make much sense to me.

And the second `for` loop after `zip()` repeats content.